# Plasma Mobile in MultiROM Manager on Nexus 5

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, rom, multirom-manager

I tried to install Plasma Mobile on Nexus 5. It is very important to me to start testing it in MultiROM Manager first (with some other mobile operating systems).
I followed [this](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Mobile/MultiROM) tutorial.
In section:

> Finally install the Plasma Phone

on:

> It will take while to download. After download is over, it will reboot to recovery, in recovery it will make real installation process, so drink a coffee meanwhile.. ;-)

I got error:

> cheching file device-687a931c47e1...d6b63d42054.tar.xz..FAILED

I checked "dev" (version 8), but I got same error on: "dev-proposed" (version 1).
I have:

1. OS version (official Nexus 5 latest update - 6 IX 2016):

   > Andorid 6.01
2. Kernel:

   > 3.4.0-g4ad03fa-dirty
   > tasadar@tyene #1
   > Tue Feb 9 21:30:30 CET 2016
3. Compilation number:

   > M0B31E

In MultiROM (patched - like in tutorial) I have installed:

1. > MultiROM v33
2. > Recovery 2016-02-10 (0)"
3. > Kernel: Stock 6.0 and 6.1

How can I solve this error message?

Comment: Edited to correct your MultiROM tutorial link. Better off directing these to MultiROM or Plasma XDA-Developers threads (if any). Also, thanks for interesting mention of Plasma Mobile - gotta go look it up.

Comment: @AndyYan: "gotta go look it up" Did you checked it? Any tips? I will create a topic at xda-developers and reference this question to it.

Comment: I actually mean figuring out what Plasma is... sorry for leaving you anticipating :(